# I am having a problem in runing if else program in java basically the else statement is not printed if the if statement is false

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class rtr { 
    public static void main(String args[])throws java.io.IOException {
        int age;
        System.out.print("Enter your age"); 
        age = (int) System.in.read(); 
        if(age >= 18) System.out.println("You are elligible for voting"); 
        else System.out.println("You are not elligible for voting");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Enter your age 12
You are elligible for voting
```

Comment: Hint: Print out the value of  `age` after you read it in and you'll see that your error has nothing to do with the if else.

Comment: Eligible has one "l".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading in  characters.

Try adding a:

```
 System.out.println(age);
```

to do some basic debugging to see how the characters get converted to an int?

Try using a `Scanner` and you can use the `nextInt()` method to make sure the value is converted correctly.

Comment: Thanks  the problem  is solved

Answer (score 1):

`System.in.read()` reads the next byte of data. so In this case, it reads 1. ASCII value of 1 is 49 so your age gets initialized to 49.

Try this instead.

```
     System.out.print("Enter your age"); 
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```